# How do I make VirtualBox start when Ubuntu Server starts?

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, boot

I have VirtualBox and I want to install MS Windows in it. How can I make VirtualBox start when Ubuntu Server does, so that I don't need to manually start Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

virtualbox --help:

```
--startvm <vmname|UUID>    start a VM by specifying its UUID or name
```

You can add this command to startup apps at `System->Preferences->Startup applications`.

In case you don't have GUI (you mentioned that you are running Ubuntu Server) you probably are looking for a way to [run your virtual machine in "headless" mode](http://www.google.lt/search?q=headless+vbox). However you won't be able to install anything in headless mode, so you need to prepare your virtual machine on computer with GUI enabled.

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu Server comes with a graphic interface

Comment: Your `VBoxHeadless` might support graphical connection using VNC. Run it with the `--help` option to see whether your does.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're about to create a /etc/init.d script, just stick the command to start the VM in /etc/rc.local. Very easy, very simple. You didn't say whether you were using a GUI or give much of any detail at all so I don't know exactly what command you'd be putting in there. Skirmantas's suggestion to check virtualbox --help is a good one.